# Why Spring MVC doesn't validate parameter with generic type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

> I know there are several questions related this subject. This question is about "why"

When resolving argument in controller, validation not works as expected.

both of codes below not working

```java
public void foo(@RequestBody @Valid List<MyDTO> requests) {
 ...
}
```

```java
public void foo(@RequestBody List<@Valid MyDTO> requests) {
 ...
}
```

However, when I add `@Validated` annotation to my controller, then it works.

After I digged into the code, I found that the argument resolver just finds annotations by `getParameterAnnotation` in java.lang.reflect and this doesn't extract `@Valid` annotation in type like `List<@Valid MyDTO>`.

However, proxy handler of `@Validated` can extract it through `ParameterizedType` in java.lang.reflect. (this may be wrong `cause I'm not good at debugging)

Why are they different ? Is this just mistake ? or Is there any reason?

Comment: They are different as they serve different purposes. The Spring MVC support for validation is mainly for validating form/request objects and not method parameters. Method parameter validation is mainly intended to validate the user input on services etc. They work differently and also report different errors to the user.

Comment: As I understood, the validation in MVC is interested in requested object's integrety itself(which means, doesn't expect the object to contain proper value complying with my domain logic), so when `List` is given, it only cares about the size of list or something else. is this thought right ?

Comment: The first part is correct, the second isn't.